# How does one get a child of a parent class from another child

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have 4 classes: A, B which is a child of A, D which is a child of A and C which is a child of B.

Basically:

```java
public class A {  }

public class B extends A {  }
public class C extends B {  }

public class D extends A {  }
```

Is there any possible way to get an object type `D` from a `C` class object in java?

Comment: No. `D` and `C` are unrelated. You will need to write conversion code based on your logic.

Comment: @ernest_k Yeah i thought so, i was just checking if there's an easier way. Thanks!